# Why won't C++/WinRT IDL file allow me to define a method with a pointer as a parameter?

Tags: pointers, idl, c++-winrt, midl

I am using code in a C# UWP project to generate data in a short array, pass this data to code in a C++/WinRT Component project (using a pointer and the array's length), modify the data, and then pass back a new array (using a pointer and the array's length) to the C# code. Using the code below, I do not immediately get errors. However, building the C++/WinRT project fails, as my idl file gets the error: MIDL2025 [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting an identifier near "*".

Is it possible to pass pointers from C# to C++/WinRT? (If you see any additional issues with my code or its efficiency, feel free to let me know.)

I have scoured the internet for all information regarding C++/WinRT (not C++/CX) and .idl files. I do not think anything more than a few years old will be accurate for C++/WinRT. C++/WinRT was released on June 23, 2015 and anything before then regarding WinRT will really just be C++/CX. I made my code by following the example here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-editor/blob/master/PhotoEditor/Photo.idl. Also, I believe that the idl files in C++/WinRT are actually MIDL 3.0. Looking at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#types, I changed my idl file to accept `Int32` rather than `int` and `Int16*` rather than `short*` (please let me know if that is unnecessary). I have researched a bit about the `out` keyword, but it did not seem to work with MIDL 3.0. To be clear I want to get back `short*` as in the pointer, not `short` as in the value.

Here is my idl file:

```
//.idl file
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyClass
    {
        MyClass();

        void DoStuff(Int32 length, Int16* inbuf, Int16* outbuf);
    }
}
```

Here is my header file:

```
//.h file
#pragma once
#include "MyClass.g.h"

namespace winrt::MyProject::implementation
{
    struct MyClass: MyClassT<MyClass>
    {
        MyClass() = default;

        void DoStuff(int length, short* inbuf, short* outbuf);
    };
}

namespace winrt::MyProject::factory_implementation
{
    struct MyClass: MyClassT<MyClass, implementation::MyClass>
    {
    };
}
```

Here is my C++ file:

```
//.cpp file
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyClass.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::MyProject::implementation
{
    void MyClass::DoStuff(int length, short* inbuf, short* outbuf)
    {
        //Process data here by editing outbuf
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: MIDL 3.0 doesn't support pointers. It does support [single-dimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#types): *"You don't need to declare a single-dimensional array before you can use it. Instead, array types are constructed by following a type name with square brackets. For example, `Int32[]` is a single-dimensional array of `Int32`."*

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for letting me know about the pointers. I decided to modify my code to have all array related coding in the C++/WinRT project. Then I will just call methods without pointer parameters across the ABI boundary.

Comment: If anyone is interested, it took me a while to find this link about C++/WinRT Component projects specifically and about auto generating the .cpp and .h files from the idl: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-events#create-a-windows-runtime-component-bankaccountwrc